# copy constructor of a vector-derived class

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, copy-constructor

I have the following classes.

```
class CA {
...
};

class CB: public vector<CA> {
...
};
```

How shall I implement the copy constructor of CB? i.e.,

```
CB(CB& cb).
```

How do I copy the content of the vector of cb in?

Comment: Please don't derive standard containers.

Comment: The compiler provided copy constructor should work just fine. However, there are reasons not to inherit from `std::vector`, *especially* publicly.

Comment: std:: containers are not meant to be derived from.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What's wrong with deriving `std::vector`? I remember one situation when I did it, just to add to my vector few additional data members...

Comment: @LihO, standard containers destructors are not virtual, which is potential UB if you delete it via base class pointer. So you CAN do this but you've got be VERY careful.

Comment: @aleguna: I had to somehow add few data members describing the content of this vector (`minVal`, `maxVal`, etc.) without changing some of the existing code... so the most reasonable solution back then seemed to me to derive `std::vector` and define few additional data members with lifetime tied to the `vector` object itself.

Comment: @juanchopanza how do i implement the copy constructor? you mean leave it blank?

Comment: @jason.Z: **undefined behavior**

Comment: @LihO private inheritance would be reasonably safe, except that it gives you access to protected methods of the base class, which might be undesirable. See [this gotw](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm).

Comment: @LihO I've seen such code before as well, and that works fine. That is why I implemented my program like this. Do you know how to implement the copy constructor? Or shall I just copy each element of the vector after its creation?

Comment: @jason.Z don't implement anything yourself. If you have C++11, you can make that explicit with `CA(const CA&)=default;`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I dont have C++11. What shall I do if I need such a copy constructor?

Comment: @jason.Z Do you *need* to implement your own copy constructor? If not, then just don't implement anything and it will work.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thank you for that *"Uses and Abuses of Inheritance"* article :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the issue with publicly inheriting from an `std::vector`, if you really need a copy constructor for your derived type (for instance, if you are managing dynamically allocated resources), then you can use the constructor initialization list, as in this example, where `Foo` takes the place of your `std::vector` in the inheritance hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  Foo() {}
  Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "Copy Foo\n";}
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
  Bar() {}
  Bar(const Bar& b) : Foo(b) {}
};

int main()
{
  Bar b1;
  Bar b2(b1);
}
```

Comment: For vector, it will be like this? i.e., `CB(const CB& cb): vector<CA>(cb) {}`

Comment: @jason.Z yes, vector is no different. It has useful copy constructors and all.

Comment: @jason.Z that looks right. Should be easy to write a small test.

Comment: previously, I was worrying about the initialization list, `vector<CA>(cb)`